# Grab date and time data for a calendar that I have read only access to

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I am looking to grab a list of events from my google calendar. I have read only access to a calendar. I don't want/need to edit these events, I just want to grab the date and time of these events.

In the Google Calendar API, I need a CalendarID. I don't necessarily have this ID because it's a read only ID that I grabbed from a website (one of those links that says "Add this calendar to your google calendar!".

Does anyone have any ideas on how I would go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you e.g. have code to access a calendar you have full access to?

Comment: @IonicSolutions I am able to access my own calendar using the python quickstart code found here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python. 

The issue is that the code to get events requires a CalendarID, but I don't have a calendar ID for the calendar that is "read only".

Comment: How do you access the calendar then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. I was able to use and edit the code in this [link](https://qxf2.com/blog/google-calendar-python/) and printed all the available calendars that I had access to (read only or not). From there, I was able to print the IDs of those calendars.